# How to merge mutliple lists in drop-down selection based on checkbox(s) selected?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Suppose we have 5 checkboxes and each has unique value mapped with respective list of elements, just in my case I have associative PHP array -

```
[100] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => NameABC [sid] => 109 ) 
                 [1] => Array ( [name] => NameDEF [sid] => 110 ) 
               ) 

[101] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => NamePQR [sid] => 337 ) 
                 [1] => Array ( [name] => NameXYZ [sid] => 339 ) 
               )
```

so the values can be mapped with each list, now by the property of checkbox you can select more than one checkbox (unlike radio button), so when such case comes the drop down list that is being populated on the basis of each checkbox selection, now comes in a merged format like on selecting OPTION 1 and OPTION 2 both the list contains all the elements mapped to both, further on de-selecting it comes back to unmerged state.

Comment: u can create this array by json output?. then i can do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after iterations on my own question, I found almost correct answer for the same. Below is the *HTML* snippet used by me in this --

```
<tr>
<td align="center"  bgcolor="#BFD5EA" width="30%"><font size="1" face="Verdana"><b>Sales Channel :&nbsp;</b></font></td>
<td bgcolor="#E4E4E4" colspan="5"><font size="1" face="Verdana" width="70%">
~foreach from=$sales_channel item=r`
    <input type="checkbox" name="salestype[]" value="~$r.ROLE`"  id="~ $r.NAME`" >~$r.NAME`&nbsp;
~/foreach`
</td>
</tr>   
<tr style="display: none" id="nafrat"><td align="center"  bgcolor="#BFD5EA" width="30%"><font size="1" face="Verdana"><b>List of Executives:</font></b></td>
<td bgcolor="#E4E4E4" colspan="5" width="70%">
    <select name="selOnlSrc[]"  id="myops" multiple size="10" ><!--@@@@Done-->
    ~foreach from=$assigner key=k item=r`
        ~foreach  from=$r item=m`
            <option id="allexec" value="all" selected>All</option>
            <option class="~$k`" class="searchSelect"  style="display: none"   value="~$m.execid`">~$m.display_name`</option>
        ~/foreach` 
    ~/foreach` 
    </select> 
</td>
```

And now most important is the jquery part --

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">  </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$("input[name=salestype[]]:checkbox").click(function() {
  var selected = new Array();
  $('#nafrat').show();
  $("input:checkbox[name=salestype[]]:checked").each(function() {
    selected.push($(this).val());
    });
  $('#myops').children('option').hide();
  var btnchk= new Array();
  btnchk = $('input:checkbox[name="salestype[]"]:checked');

  if (btnchk.length) {
  $('#allexec').show();
  }
  else {
  $('#allexec').hide();
  $('#nafrat').hide();
  }
  $.each( selected, function(i, l){
      $('.'+l).show();
      });
  selected = new Array();
  btnchk  = new Array();

});
</script>
```

For this I am able to get values in the drop-down merged on selecting two or more check-boxes and further on un-checking any one, removes the respective contents from the list below.

**NOTE**: the *HTML* displayed above contains *smarty* tags and also have some *PHP* variables like *"$assigner"* etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm oversimplifying the problem or missing a key bit of information, but could you not just:

```
$merged = array();
foreach ($list as $l)
{
    $merged[] = $l;
}
```

Where $list is the array with keys [101], [102], etc, etc?

This would leave you with:

```
$merged = Array (
            [0] => Array ( [name] => NameABC [sid] => 109 )
            [1] => Array ( [name] => NameDEF [sid] => 110 )
            [2] => Array ( [name] => NamePQR [sid] => 337 ) 
            [3] => Array ( [name] => NameXYZ [sid] => 339 )
          )
```

Or if `sid` is unique to all of the arrays, perhaps this would be more appropriate:

```
$merged = array();
foreach ($list as $l)
{
    $merged[$l['sid']] = $l['name'];
}
```

Giving you:

```
$merged = Array (
            [109] => NameABC
            [110] => NameDEF
            [337] => NamePQR
            [339] => NameXYZ
          )
```